# Java MicroBenchmarking Harness ignoring benchmark options

Tags: java-8, benchmarking, java, jmh

I am using OpenJDK JMH and although I tried annotating both the method and the class that runs it, it will still run with the defaults. I am running this benchmark from a tests folder using jUnit.

```
public class BenchmarkRunner {

    @Test
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(argv);
    }
}
```

It doesnt matter if I annotate the class or method:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(value = 3)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void testMethod()
    {
        testHashFinderMethod_1();
    }


    private void testHashFinderMethod_1()
    {
        HashFinder hashFinder_1 = new HashFinder("TeSt",'A','z');
        hashFinder_1.findHash("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running the benchmark from the `tests` folder using the jUnit `@test` annotation. Moved it and ran it from the `src` folder and it works.